# Unexpected padding under status bar

Tags: swift, uitableview, header

I have a UITableView with a header section (see picture below) but there is an unexpected padding under the status bar. The blue background color of the anonymous man indicates the header section. When I make the background color of the UITableView red the white padding under the status bar is still white, so it's not the UITableView. But I have no idea where this come from, who can help me?

Note: The image is a resized NSData String from picked Core Data.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have contentInset() somewhere?

Comment: A print of contentInset gives: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0). And when I set top to for example -100, the padding is still here.

Answer (score 0):

From storyboard, select this very viewController where your have added this view.
Go to identity inspector, under the heading View Controller there is a a subheading of Layout. Uncheck the option Adjust Scroll View Insets.
[image]

Comment: I'm using only .xib files, but setting automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets to the file's owner self does not remove the padding.

Comment: you have to set it as -- self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

Comment: Yes, I did that, like self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false, but the padding is still there

Comment: Click on tableView..Go to size inspector and check section height and footer height..it must be 1..Also please check your image...it also might hold a white line on top

Comment: I added the TableView by code, but i checked the image and there is no white space on top of it.